# What is the best way of removing reoccurring lines from a file in Bash?

Tags: bash

Folks,

I have a file that contains ldap entries and I want to remove "version: 1" lines from the second occurrence and on. I know sed can do things like this, but since I am very new, I don't know how to proceed.
This is a Solaris 10 machine and the file looks like as follows:

```
version: 1
dn: uid=tuser1,ou=people,o=example.com,o=isp
cn: tuser1
uidNumber: 3
gidNumber: 3
homeDirectory: /export/home/tuser1
loginShell: /bin/sh
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
objectClass: account
objectClass: top
uid: tuser1
shadowLastChange:
userPassword:

version: 1
dn: uid=tuser2,ou=people,o=example.com,o=isp
uidNumber: 20
cn: tuser1
gidNumber: 3
homeDirectory: /export/home/tuser2
loginShell: /bin/sh
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
objectClass: account
objectClass: top
uid: tuser1
shadowLastChange:
userPassword: 

version: 1
dn: uid=tuser3,ou=people,o=example.com,o=isp
uidNumber: 10
cn: tuser3
gidNumber: 3
homeDirectory: /export/home/tuser3
loginShell: /bin/sh
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
objectClass: account
objectClass: top
uid: tuser3
shadowLastChange:
userPassword: 

version: 1
dn: uid=loperp,ou=people,o=example.com,o=isp
uid: loperp
userPassword:
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
sn: pop
cn: loper

version: 1
dn: uid=tuser4,ou=people,o=example.com,o=isp
userPassword: 
uid: tuser4
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
sn: User4
cn: Test
```

Comment: Is it strictly 'version: 1' lines, or 'version: n' lines, or repeated lines more generally?

Comment: It is strictly version: 1 lines but I want to keep the first version :1 line and delete the rest

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [GNU sed](http://www.sunfreeware.com/programlistsparc10.html#sed)

```
sed -ni '0,/version: 1/{p; d}; /version: 1/!p' ldap.txt
```

EDIT: This was initially wrong.  When the first line wasn't version, it printed duplicates.

The GNU version is simpler.  It prints (`p`) from the beginning until the first line matching the version regex, both inclusive.  Also, for each line in that range, after printing we delete the pattern space and start a new cycle (`d`).  Basically, this means go to the beginning of the script and to the next line (this avoids double printing).  Unlike (standard) `1,/regex/`, if the first line matches, it will not continue to *another* matching line.

If we haven't `d`'ed (so we're after the first `version: 1`), we then simply print every line that doesn't match the regex (`!`).

With standard sed):

```
sed -ni 'p; /version: 1/ b nov; d; :nov /version: 1/!p; n; b nov' ldap.txt
```

This begins by simply printing every line (`p`).  After that print, if we match the regex, we branch to the `nov` (no version) label; the label name is up to us.  If we do not branch, we (`d`) delete the pattern space and start a new cycle (newline, beginning of script).  In `nov`, we print the line if it does not match (same as GNU).  We then go to a new line, and branch back to nov.  This loop continues until the end.

---

I (Jonathan Leffler) can confirm @kuti's observations on Solaris 10 standard 'sed'; what works is:

```
/bin/sed -n 'p
/version: 1/ b nov
d
:nov
/version: 1/!p
n
b nov' ldap.txt
```

The 'semi-colons in lieu of newlines' trick does not seem to work universally with Solaris 'sed'.  Specifically, at the least, there cannot be a semi-colon after any use of a label.

This seems to work:

```
/bin/sed -n 'p; /version: 1/ b nov
d; :nov
/version: 1/!p; n; b nov' ldap.txt
```

(*I can't think how to present the fix in a comment - the multiline formatting is crucial here.*)

Comment: I tried the first suggestion without the -i option, it works but deletes all occurences, which is not what I am trying to accomplish. I want to keep the first ocurrence of version: 1 but delete the rest....

Comment: @kuti, are you sure you're using GNU sed?  The default Solaris version is not.  Did you try the second solution?

Comment: Here is what I get:

root@solix# sed -n 'p; /version: 1/ b nov; d; :nov /version: 1/!p; n; b nov' zdir1-user-entry-full.txt
Label too long: p; /version: 1/ b nov; d; :nov /version: 1/!p; n; b nov

Comment: Hmm, I posted a version (still second) with one-character labels.  Try that.

Comment: @Matthew, Perfect. That one works. I really appreciate it. Could you explain a little bit what is going on inside sed? a bit cryptic to me. what do p, b nov elements do inside your sed?

Comment: @kuti, I added explanations.  Let me know if I can clarify anything else.

Comment: @Matthew, thanks It is more clear now, looks like I need to read more about sed :), happy camper now....

Answer (score 2):

A simple answer uses awk:

```
awk '{ if ($0 ~ /^version: 1$/) { if (count++ == 0) print; }
       else print;
     }'
```

This assumes that you really mean you want only the first 'version: 1' line and don't mind keeping multiple 'version: 2' lines, etc.

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. I need the first occurence of version :1 and delete the rest of the version 1's from the list.

Comment: @kuti: I'm puzzled - you say "that's not what I meant" but then go on to request what (the bug-fixed version of) my answer gives you.

Comment: hmm. It deleted all occurences in mine when I tried your awk solution.Maybe I did not explain well the problem.
Long story short, I have a list of users that I need to get their details from the ldap server. I do this in a for loop:
for i in `cat $LDAP1-user-list.txt`
do
ldapsearch -h $LDAP1 -D "cn=Directory Manager" -w $PWD -b o=$DOMAIN,o=$MYO uid=$i >> $LDAP1-user-entry-full.txt
done

Above for loop inevitably gets all the information I need but with extra version: 1's after each user. I need to keep the first version: 1 and delete the rest, since this is a standard ldiff file.

Comment: @kuti: When I tried the awk solution on Solaris 10 with both GNU and Sun versions of awk on the test data from the question, I got the first 'version: 1' in the output.  The comments about 'version: 2' etc are not directly relevant - you only have 'version: 1' lines in your data and don't need to worry about alternatives (or, if the version ever changes, you'll have to do a good deal of work, not only here but everywhere else).  You could, of course, adapt the loop in your comment to add the 'version: 1' line up front, then for each ldapsearch, delete the version line since you don't want it.

Answer (score 0):

here's another awk version

```
awk '/version: 1/{c++}c>1{gsub("version: 1","")}1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using man 1 ed we can mark the line containing the first match and increment it by 1 to get:

```
#  'm+1,$  
#  ... which creates a line address space of:  
#  /first line matched + 1/,/last line/

# http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/doku.php?id=howto:edit-ed
[[ $(grep -c -m 1 '^version: 1' file) -eq 1 ]] && \
cat <<-'EOF' | sed -e 's/^ *//' -e 's/ *$//' | ed -s file
   H
  /^version: 1/km
  'm+1,$g/^version: 1/d
  wq
EOF
```